# Testing Devices in Hostile Wireless Networks

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, benchmarking

I'm attempting to benchmark the power usage of a device that sends data over wifi. This device uses some logic to attempt to retry sending data in the event of network failures. To better simulate the real world I was attempting to look into how to create a wireless network that is flaky. Basically:

1. Drops packets.
2. Simulates roaming.
3. Simulates various signal strengths.
4. Simulates multiple devices talking over each other.

I haven't been able to find a way to do this. Does anyone have any pointers on how to set up a purposely bad, and reproducible bad, network?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What you're asking isn't how wireless devices are usually tested. I've never even heard of a device or software that would do this, as that's not the way real testing's done. However all there boils from the client's perspective down to 2 things: bandwidth and transfer speed. So for starters, what hardware do you have available for labbing?

Comment: On the second thought these instructions are available all over the internet... read a few articles on how to configure an AP for best possible wireless performance, where to place the AP to minimize interference and so on - then do the exact opposite. That'll take you a few steps further. Roaming behavior you can't really test except for actually roaming between APs.

Comment: That's the first approach I had but I'm assuming there is some better way to qualify wifi devices. I'm assuming there is either some piece of software to manage an AP or a special wifi network devices that simulates various failures. That's what I'd like to get to in this question: what's the right way to do this.